# cannot send an http/https request to an external API in MEAN JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, mean-stack, meanjs

I am developing an application on MEAN JS. I am new on MEAN JS. 
I want to access an external API to get a json respone as following -
`{"id":"7gd6ud7ud5r0c","name":"jack","zip":"94109","gender":"Male"}` 


I have this reference [here (https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)..

But I dont know how to use the http/https request inside a client controller.

Here is my ***express.js***

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var fs = require('fs'),
http = require('http'),     // required already
https = require('https'),   // required already
express = require('express'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
.....
.....
.....
```

Here is my ***invite.client.controller.js***

```
    'use strict';
    angular.module('core').controller('InviteController', ['$scope', 
    'Authentication', '$http',
        function($scope, Authentication, $http) {
        // This provides Authentication context.
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

     $scope.getMembersFromAPI = function(){

            ***************************************
            // this block shows error ReferenceError: require is not defined
            var http = require('http'),  
                https = require('https');
            ***************************************
            var options = {
              hostname: 'https://api.somedemodp.com/v5/td?api_key=ec96c9afcbb6bbb8f5a687bd7&email=vlad@rapleafdemo.com',
              path: '/',
              method: 'GET'
            };

            var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
              console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
              console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

              res.on('data', function(d) {
                process.stdout.write(d);
              });
            });
            req.end();

            req.on('error', function(e) {
              console.error(e);
            });

        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...are you confusing your angular and express code?  You don't use require in angular.  You use dependency injection.

Angular is front-end, express is backend.  They are decoupled.

```
angular.module('core').controller('InviteController', ['$scope', 
'Authentication', '$http',
    function($scope, Authentication, $http)
```

This is where you do dependency injection (similar to require in node/express) You have already injected $http.

You can actually just call the external API directly from within angular using an $http call - from the docs:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// this callback will be called asynchronously
// when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: ok. I am not sure that the modules are loaded into app as dependencies or not. confused also.

Comment: You are dealing with two different monsters here - node/express and angular.  They each have their own way of loading external modules (like http or $http).  You need to think of them as separate entities that communicate with each other.  You really should read this if you aren't that familiar with the concept:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: thanks for the info. but as i am working with https, so should I use $https instead of $http? The script is running now but giving "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error.

Comment: You can just use $http with angular, just be sure to include the https in the url parameter.

Comment: and how can I get rid of this cross domain access? I think i need to change something.... http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: or should i change the function u suggested with the cors.org ?

Comment: If you are making the ajax call from angular you shouldn't need to do anything with CORS.  It may be an issue with the API you are trying to interface with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74835/discussion-between-tpie-and-mithun-sen).

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into this problem. I suggest to reading this blog: [calling third party web api's from the mean stack](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/calling-third-party-web-apis-from-the-mean-stack/)

The problem you have is due to the fact that browsers block cross-domain calls. The way to go is by contacting the API from the server and sending that onto the front end.

**Note**: I haven't tried this myself but, appearently by enabling CORS on the receiving end + sending the right headers will allow you to do cross domain calls from the front end.